# Dynamics CRM 4.0: Check workflow execution time against recurring daily hours

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm building a workflow to route a case based on time of day:
e.g., if the case is created (workflow fires on create) between 7am-5pm local, then I want to route the case to a "Customer Service" Queue.    If the case is created any time outside of 7a-5p, I want to route it to a 'holding' queue for pickup the next business day.

Any way to do that using the onboard WF toolkit?  I'm kind of leaning toward a custom workflow at the moment, but I really want to avoid that as I'd like to make this in a way that my client can understand and maintain.

Thanks!
-RC

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to specify just a time range like you want using just the native UI.

You could create a custom "Within Working Hours" workflow assembly and still have it be easy to use, though.  Your custom wf assembly would take 3 inputs:

- Working Hours Start
- Working House End
- Current Case Created Time

As I'm sure you can guess, the values you would give it would be 7, 5, and the case's Created On value.  The custom wf assembly could then return true if the Case was created within the hours specified by the first two parameters supplied.

Any variation of this custom wf assembly should probably do the trick for you.